# Struggling to figure out how I would run this analysis (Repeated Measures ANOVA)

Tags: anova, python, repeated-measures, biostatistics, statsmodels

**Conceptualization of RM ANOVA:** So the way that I conceptualize repeated measures ANOVA is that I have some dependent variable that is measured across different levels of one or more independent variables. So if I wanted to see if the valence of an image (positive, negative, neutral) makes people squirm in their seats (DV: how many seconds they squirm) I would basically measure someone watching a positive, then a negative, then a neutral image. Then I would compare them to each other using a RM ANOVA.

**Where I am getting confused is with my data.**

Here is a dumbed-down example of my experiment:

I had people see an image, and rate their attitude. Later, they rated their attitude again of the same photo, and told me whether they remembered or forgot the image.

My DV is attitude.

My IVs are Valence: (positive, negative) and Memory: (Remembered or Forgot).

**My hypothesis:** For the images they Remembered (both positive and negative) their emotional judgements would be the same across first and second judgments (difference scores of around 0). For Forgot images, their emotional judgements would be sustained for negative, but not positive images.

But, when I try and run a 2-way RM ANOVA, I can't figure out how to do it.

**DATA:**

```
|Participant|Judgment   |Time              |Memory        |Valence   |
| ----------| ----------| ---------------  | ------------ | -------- |
| 1         | 5.6       | first judgement  | remembered   | positive |
| 1         | 6.7       | first judgement  | forgot       | negative |
| 1         | 2.4       | first judgement  | remembered   | negative |
| 1         | 6.2       | second judgement | forgot       | positive |
| 1         | 3.6       | second judgement | remembered   | positive |
```

So, rather than having a judgment per each level of each independent variable, I have a judgment for each level of each independent variable, but also by TIME, and not all levels of each variable have the same amount of data (because different people remember more than others).

I then assumed that I would use "time" as a within-subjects factor, but pingouin (and statsmodels) only allow two within-subjects variables:

```
pg.mixed_anova(dv='Judgment', within= ['Memory', 'Valence'],
subject='participant', data=df)
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please format your data clearly.

Comment: It's not clear that repeated-measure ANOVA can test your hypothesis. When you say:  "For Forgot images, their emotional judgements would be sustained for negative, but not positive images," it sounds like the difference scores would be around 0 for both types of image, but for different reasons. For negative valence, it would be near 0 because of sustained judgement; for positive valence, it would average close to 0 just because of random variability between judgments. It sounds like you might want to evaluate the _variance_ of judgments instead. Please edit the question to clarify.